# Transparent UIImage in iphone app's Document folder

Tags: iphone, uiimage, document, transparent, uiimagejpegrepresentation

As i am saving a image which has transparent part but while saving it in Document folder, the transparent part changed to white.

Below is the code ....

```
NSData *dataPhoto = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageBigPhoto, 1.0);
        //NSData *dataPhoto = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageBigPhoto);
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,  YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullPathWithFoldername=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"PhotoFolderName"]];

        //NSLog(@"%@",fullPathWithFoldername);

        NSString *fullPath = [fullPathWithFoldername stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];

        [dataPhoto writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I see you've switched from PNG to JPEG format. Is there was the same problem with the PNG?

Comment: JPEG doesn't do transparency.

Answer (score 2):

JPEG images don't support transparency.  PNG images do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have commented your PNG Representation of Image, JPEG Representation does not save transparency. Just Enable you commented code and try.